# How do I Link_to an external URL in new tab/window and also run controller method?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of links being rendered from the database.

When a link is clicked I'd like the href to open in a new tab/window and to also call a controller method so I can update a database field (I'm recording the time/date the link is clicked).

I haven't found any solutions that link to an external URL aswell as acess a controller method. Is it something I'd need to rely on JSON for?

Answer (score 0):

simply:

You have to provide `http://`

```
<%= link_to "Google", "http://www.google.com", :target => '_blank', :id="ex-link"%>
```

To hit your controller's action you may use `ajax`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ex-link").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "<%= your_action_in_controller_path %>",
            data: {p1: val1, p2: val2},   // you may pass parameter
            dataType:'script',
            beforeSend: function(){
                // code if you need 
            },
            success: function(response){
                // code if you need
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to call remote => true in the link_to to use ajax?

Comment: Also, in URL, do I simply call the controller action name - e.g. <%= visit_feed %>

Comment: And passing the ID in 'data', would that be data: {id} ?

Comment: no, you have to provide path of the action. You can get it by `rake routes` and you have to put `data: {p1: val1, p2: val2},` like this. It will generate `http://exmple.com/your_action?p1=val1&p2=val2`